# sending json from andriod to php using get or post method and exatract the values of json in php

Tags: php

I can send json from android to php but i'm unable to extract the data from json object in php. Can anyone help me to that in php?

I tried json_decode($json)  to decode the json data.

What I was doing is I'm sending json object from android in get method and receiving the data in php side like this..
`<?php
$json=$_GET['data'];
$d_json=json_decode($json) or json_decode($json,true);
?>`

but when I was trying to access "$d_json['meal'][0]['name]" or 
"$d_json->meal[0]->name" it was showing illegal index.

Comment: you should post the data associated with the request perhaps

Comment: Did you check what the result array you get after decoding json object?

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to **print the $d_json to the screen** - to see what is the value it holds.

If $d_json is not empty, but it is not an array (but a string) I would try a little bit of formatting:

```
$d_json = json_decode( stripslashes( $json ), true );
```

Then print_r (or var_dump, var_export) the result to see whether it returns an array.

Comment: After doing so as you said I got this
"stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line no 4"

Comment: It seems that your $json is already an array, not a JSON string. If that is true, then you cannot json_decode() it, as this function takes a JSON encoded string as first param (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Could this be the case? What does the $_GET['data'] return? Can you validate it with JSON validator - that it is in a correct JSON format?